# Pausing program until next startup

Tags: java, hibernation

I have a program which bruteforces an AES256 encryption, how would I pause the program when the computer goes into shutdown/or reboot and continue at the same point until the next boot of the system?

A sort of hibernate of the program.

Comment: You have to write down the state of the program to disk. (The content of all variables relevant to the progress of the algorithm.) And then load these values back into the variables once you restart the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked three things here.

1- How can I check when the OS goes reboot/shutdown

Solution: 
You can make an empty invisible window, and add WindowListener to it. It will receive windowClosing event on windows.

You can find an example [HERE](http://www.coderanch.com/t/327529/java/java/Detect-windows-shutdown)

2- How can I save the state of my BruteForce process and pause to start again when system goes up.

Solution:
Here is easy, you must serialize. These will save the state of your class/classes to deserialize when system goes UP again. You can study [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm)

3- How know when startup the programm again when OS goes UP?

Solution:
You can put your program in initialization process of your OS. When it starts, you check if there is anything to deserialize and do it, restoring the process of the BruteForce.

Comment: As one guy said in the link of solution 1 in code ranch; the shutdown hook may not work as an solution to check when OS goes shutdown

Comment: That is going to be OS dependent, also, if a shutdown hook doesn't get invoked, I'd be surprised if a shutting window event /does/ happen

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with part 2 and 3 of @Thufir's answer, but regarding part 1 it assumes that you are running a GUI.

Instead of this I would add a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) into the JVM and write the state of my program at that point.  You can do this using the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
   public void run() {
       // your serialization code goes here
   }
});
```

Comment: What's your experience with this hook? I seem to be encountering situations where it doesn't execute.

Comment: I use it in a production system to control a system shutdown; can you elaborate on when you don't see it working?

Comment: The only issue I'm aware of is a difference in behaviour between SIGKILL vs SIGTERM, but you'll have the same problem with SIGKILL as you do with a window based version- the OS is hard killing your process so all bets are off anyway.  The only way to remedy this is to periodically write your application state out and recover from that point

Comment: Well it's the last one indeed. You gave me a nice idea to work with now thank you.